# Unwanted text file is creating while calling a URL through Cron

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, sh

In our application we are configured number of Cron jobs for running some routine tasks.We are working on Ruby on Rails. I will provide the flow we are using.

**crontab**

```
*/2 *    * * *   user  sh file_path/test.sh
```

**test.sh**

```
wget https://domain.com/url/key
```

**routes.rb**

```
post "/url/:key" => "cron_job_controller#action"
```

**cron_job_controller.rb**

```
def action
   if params[:key] && params[:key] == "key"
      ---do some actions----
   end
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html {render :status => Rack::Utils.status_code(:ok), :nothing => true}
   end
end
```

The job is getting executed and all the process is completing successfully. but after getting response 200 an unwanted text file is getting generated with name as the value of key we are passing in the home folder. for example **key,key.1,key.2,etc....**. Providing the console result below.

```
LAP-PS009:~/work$ sh file_path/test.sh 
--2015-02-13 14:58:16--  http://localhost:3000/url/key
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:3000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `key'

[ <=>                                    ] 1           --.-K/s   in 0s      
2015-02-13 14:58:18 (89.3 KB/s) - `key' saved [1]
```

Because of this we have to monitor and remove these unwanted files manually. So I am requesting to suggest a permanent solution for this problem. Waiting for the replays. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your `test.sh`  script will copy a file called `key` down, and because it's set to `*/2` it will run every 2 minutes.  Are you sure that it's not this that's generating the file rather than the controller?

Comment: Actually you show this happening in your post!  So, your question actually looks like "When i run this script to download a file, a file is downloaded, why is this happening?".  I may be misreading things tho.  Can you explain a bit more about what you actually WANT to happen?

Comment: @max */2 is just an example. The 'key' I mention is an example. Actually it is a string parameter which send with the request for authorizing the request,and make sure that it is called from our system only. But here when I called the post as mentioned above a garbage file is creating in folder with same name as the parameter value. So I want to avoid that. I think you got my point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you need just to pick up an API endpoint, you might use `curl` with respective [*CRUD*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) action (`POST`/`PUT`/`DELETE`).

Once you are stuck to `wget`, do the following:

```
wget https://domain.com/url/key -o /dev/null -O /dev/null
```

The above will redirect an output to nowhere preventing you directory from being garbaged.

Comment: Sorry I didn't checked inside folder. Still it is creating, Why I was misunderstood because in terminal it is not showing any trace of creation. But after running it is still creating a garbage file.Extremely sorry.

Comment: @Menon It’s impossible. The aforementioned `wget` command would not create any output for sure. What operating system are you using? Does explicit call to `wget https://domain.com/url/key -o /dev/null` produces any garbage?

Comment: Yes the explicit call also creating garbage file, I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: That said, if you create new absolutely empty directory, `cd` into it and execute `wget https://domain.com/url/key -o /dev/null` the new file named `key` appears? It’s really hard to believe.

Comment: Ya, For me also. The temporary solution I did was using 'rm key' after the 'wget' command inside the 'sh' file. But it is not working always.

Comment: GNU Wget 1.13.4 built on linux-gnu

Comment: OK, this would work for you: `wget https://domain.com/url/key -o /dev/null -O /dev/null`.

Comment: Ya, It is working it seems. Thanks. Is there anything to do with 'wget' version?

Comment: @Menon No, it has nothing to do with `wget` version. It is how it’s supposed to be run to suppress everything.